# How to make line invisible to datacursormode

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an application that create lines on the cursor position. When I enter the `datacursormode` to create `datatips`, it create on the lines that follow the cursor position.

I was wondering how to remove them from being visible to the `datacursormode`, but don't making them invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, make its handle HitTest off.

I.e, the line is created by a plot or line command, then add the following pair value at its end:

```
plot(…,'HitTest','off');
line(…,'HitTest','off');
```

This will make the line invisible for the datacursormode.